# Animating UIView frame.origin

Tags: animation, uiview

I have seen some sample code online regarding a simple UIView slide-in or slide-out. It makes sense to have a UIView start with its coordinates off the screen (negative) and then the animation parameter simply changes the UIView's frame. So first question is: does this provide the most obvious method?

However, in my code, the frame origin is not assignable. I get the Xcode error for that line that says as much.

I simply want to do something like this inside an animation:

```
self.viewPop.frame.origin.y=100;
```

Any help is appreciated.

---

**UPDATE**

I have solved this problem. The technique I discovered is to assign your view's frame to another CGRect, and make changes to that CGRect, then assign it back to the frame:

```
CGRect frame = self.moveView.frame;
frame.origin.x = newvalue.


[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{ 

    self.moveView.frame = frame;

}];
```

Comment: Move your solution into an answer, then mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have solved this problem. The technique I discovered is to assign your view's frame to another CGRect, and make changes to that CGRect, then assign it back to the frame:

```
CGRect frame = self.moveView.frame;
frame.origin.x = newvalue.


[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{ 

    self.moveView.frame = frame;

}];
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, it's nice to have a UIView category around for this type of thing:

```
@interface UIView (JCUtilities)

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat frameX;

-(CGFloat)frameX;
-(void)setFrameX:(CGFloat)newX;

@end

@implementation UIView (JCUtilities)

- (CGFloat)frameX {
    return self.frame.origin.x;
}

- (void)setFrameX:(CGFloat)newX {
    self.frame = CGRectMake(newX, self.frame.origin.y,
                            self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
}
```